# Can I change my MachineGUID on Windows?

Tags: windows, id

I wonder how stable a machineGUID is. Can a user change it? If so how and what would happen to there Windows auth key?

Answer (score 2):

It can be found here:

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid

You need admin permissions to change it.

Here's some C# code to do it:

```
var machineGuid = Registry.LocalMachine; 
machineGuid = machineGuid.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl);
```

No idea if it will change the windows auth key.